# How many instances do I need for high availability with Azure "Web Sites"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How many instances do I need to configure to ensure that my site stays available during *planned* maintenance performed on the underlying OS/VM.

I understand the availability model for ***web roles***, but I am not clear if it is the same for ***web sites*** on Azure.

With ***web roles***, you have to configure at least 2 instances in separate upgrade domains to get the SLA from Microsoft and to ensure that your site is routinely available.  This ensures that your site will stay available as Microsoft performs maintenance on the underlying OS (updating to a newer version of the OS image, etc).

What's the equivalent story for ***web sites***?  Do I need to have two instances of my web site or does Microsoft proactively move my site to a new VM before they perform maintenance (since web sites are more "managed" than web roles, that seems like it may be possible that they do this)?

Does the answer change between Free, Shared, and Reserved ***web sites***?

Note, I understand that during sudden, unplanned downtime, having a single instance means my site will be unavailable until it is restarted on a new node.  I am not worried about that for my low-volume hobby site.  What I am more interested in is the routine, planned maintenance activities that are much more common than unplanned failures of the VM or host hardware.

**Edit for clarification:** Clearly, having 2 (or more) reserved instances is going to be the best option for high availability, but that is cost prohibitive for a hobby site at just short of $120 per month. My question really is if a single Shared or Reserved instance is going to have routine downtime for planned maintenance. I'm specifically wondering if anyone has concrete information on this (from a blog post I may have missed or from a phone call with the Microsoft support guys, etc).  Maybe the answer is "no one knows because Microsoft hasn't clarified how things will work outside of the preview yet".

I also don't want to get hung up on the term "High Availability".  I guess I am just looking for "Not Low Availability".  It's just a hobby site, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Azure Web Sites are still **in preview**. That means that there is no SLA what so ever. When the Web Sites come out of preview, I would suggest having at least **2 reserved** instances for high-availability.

Both Free and Shared instance imply usage quotas - CPU/Memory/Bandwitdth (Shared has no quota on the bandwidth, but still apply quota on CPU and Memory).

Having usage quotas in place is controversial to `High Availability` in my understanding for that term. That's why I suggest **Reserved**. It is same for the number of instances.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SLA since Web Sites are still in preview, but I also wondered about downtime during updates and found an explanation on twitter from a member of the Azure team:
https://twitter.com/nirmsk/status/342087643779198977

Apparently they keep a "buffer" of machines that are used if the current machine needs to be rebooted, crashes, or you change the scaling options (between Shared and Reserved).

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple instances won't solve the problem since any change you make on one instance is automatically propagated to all other instances.

However Azure websites now supports having a staging version of your website and swapping between staging and production versions of the site. That would be ideal for your scenario. See here for more info: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/